# Можно ли увеличить pool Integerов в Java

Tags: java, jvm

Известно, если сравнивать 2 объекта типа Integer через == в диапазоне от -128 до 127, то будут сравнивать значения в этих объектах, а если число не входит в этот диапазон, то будут сравниваться ссылки на объекты.
Вопрос заключается в том можно ли увеличить размер этого poolа, если да, то как? Чтобы сравнивать и бОльшие числа через ==
Например чтобы стало так:

```
Integer a = 800;
Integer b = 800;
System.out.println(a == b); //true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В обоих случаях сравниваются ссылки. Просто по очевидным причинам для чисел из пула равенство ссылок будет равенством и значений. Но использовать это - крайне опрометчивое решение, так как кэширование чисел - это особенность реализации **конкретной версии конкретной JVM**, а значит ваша программа может не работать на другой JVM или даже может перестать работать в следующей версии этой же JVM.

Изменить размер кэша в HotSpot вы всё же можете, указав ключ `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<размер>`.

Comment: А можно через аргументы передаваемые при запуске java программы изменить размер poola? Или в настройках jvm входящей в состав jdk 8 задать его размер?

Comment: @Kotysh дополнил ответ.

Comment: а отрицательный диапазон можно сделать больше? Не могу найти ключ

Comment: @Kotysh нет, нельзя.